# What is the path variable for configuring CodeShip with Amazon?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, codeship

I have a local git repo and I am trying to do continuous integration and deployment using Codeship. https://documentation.codeship.com

I have the github hooked up to the continuous integration and it seems to work fine.

I have an AWS account and a bucket on there with my access keys and permissions.

I am trying to configure my automatic deployment on codeship:

```
S3
AWS Access Key ID: ****************4VOA
AWS Secret Access Key: ************************************uC4j
Region: eu-west-1
Local Path: .\Users\user\Documents\projects\test
S3 Bucket: test-app-name-bucket
ACL: bucket-owner-full-control
```

It keeps giving me an error saying that the local path does not exist. What am I supposed to put for that field?

Answer (score 1):

The *Local Path* on Codeship is the directory that you want to deploy relative to your repository root (by default).

If you have a directory called `site` in your repository and you want to only upload this directory you would use `./site` as the *Local Path*. If you want to upload the complete repository you could use `./` instead.